# Using writeFragment to Update a Field Belonging to an Object?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm trying to get my first `writeFragment` working.

Here's the object shape:

```
resolutions {
  _id
  name
  completed
  goals {
    _id
    name
    completed
  }
}
```

I've just run a mutation on the client that successfully adds a new `goal`, and now I'm trying to get the client page to auto-update and show the new goal that was just added.

I've got `readFragment` working. It reads in the Resolution successfully. I'm reading in the Resolution, rather than the goals, because as a field belonging to resolution, the goals don't have an id of their own.

Here's my `update` function, showing `readFragment` and `writeFragment`:

```js
<Mutation
  mutation={CREATE_GOAL}
  update={(cache, { data: { createGoal } }) => {
    let resId = 'Resolution:' + resolutionId;

    const theRes = cache.readFragment({
      id: resId,
      fragment: GET_FRAGMENT_GOAL,
    });

    theRes.goals = theRes.goals.concat([createGoal]); //<== THIS WORKS

    cache.writeFragment({
      id: resId,
      fragment: SET_FRAGMENT_GOAL,
      data: { __typename: 'Resolution', goals: theRes.goals },
      });
    }}
>
```

...and here's the gql for the fragments:

```
   const GET_FRAGMENT_GOAL = gql`
    fragment targetRes on resolutions {
      name
      completed
      goals {
        _id
        name
        completed
      }
    }
  `;


  const SET_FRAGMENT_GOAL = gql`
    fragment targetGoal on resolutions {
      __typename
      goals
    }
  `;
```

Here's a console error I'm getting:

> You are using the simple (heuristic) fragment matcher, but your queries contain union or interface types.
>
> Apollo Client will not be able to able to accurately map fragments.To make this error go away, use the IntrospectionFragmentMatcher as described in the docs: http://dev.apollodata.com/react/initialization.html#fragment-matcher

I read up on IntrospectionFragmentMatcher and it looks like mega-overkill for my situation. It appears I'm doing something else wrong. Here's the other error I'm getting at the same time:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

What's wrong with my call to writeFragment?

Comment: Maybe the sub fields of `goals` should be added to `SET_FRAGMENT_GOAL` just like in `GET_FRAGMENT_GOAL`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After quite a few hours of study, I learned a *lot* about fragments!

I got it working. Here are the updated fragment and query definitions:

```
import gql from "graphql-tag";

let resolutionQueryFragments = {
    goalParts: gql`
    fragment goalParts on Goal {
        _id
        name
        completed
    }
  `,
};


resolutionQueryFragments.resolutionGoals = gql`
    fragment resolutionGoals on Resolution {
        goals{
            _id
            name
            completed   
        }
    }
`;

const GET_RESOLUTIONS = gql`
  query Resolutions {
    resolutions {
      _id
      name
      completed
      ...resolutionGoals
    }
     user {
      _id
    }
  }
  ${resolutionQueryFragments.resolutionGoals}
`;

const CREATE_RESOLUTION = gql`
    mutation createResolution($name: String!) {
      createResolution(name: $name) {
        __typename
        _id
        name
        ...resolutionGoals
        completed
      }
    }
    ${resolutionQueryFragments.resolutionGoals}
`;

const GET_RESOLUTIONS_FOR_MUTATION_COMPONENT = gql`
  query Resolutions {
    resolutions {
      _id
      name
      completed
      ...resolutionGoals
    }
  }
     ${resolutionQueryFragments.resolutionGoals}
`;

const CREATE_GOAL = gql`
  mutation createGoal($name: String!, $resolutionId: String!) {
    createGoal(name: $name, resolutionId: $resolutionId) {
        ...goalParts
      }
  }
     ${resolutionQueryFragments.goalParts}
`;

export {resolutionQueryFragments, GET_RESOLUTIONS, GET_RESOLUTIONS_FOR_MUTATION_COMPONENT, CREATE_RESOLUTION, CREATE_GOAL}
```

...and here's the updated Mutation component:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import {graphql} from "react-apollo";
import {Mutation} from "react-apollo";
import {withApollo} from "react-apollo";
import {resolutionQueryFragments, CREATE_GOAL} from '../../imports/api/resolutions/queries';

const GoalForm = ({resolutionId, client}) => {
    let input;

    return (
        <Mutation
            mutation={CREATE_GOAL}
            update={(cache, {data: {createGoal}}) => {
                let resId = 'Resolution:' + resolutionId;
                let currentRes = cache.data.data[resId];
                let theGoals = cache.readFragment({
                    id: resId,
                    fragment: resolutionQueryFragments.resolutionGoals
                });
                theGoals = theGoals.goals.concat([createGoal]);
                cache.writeFragment({
                    id: resId,
                    fragment: resolutionQueryFragments.resolutionGoals,
                    data: {goals: theGoals}
                });
            }}
        >
            {(createGoal, {data}) => (
                <div>
                    <form
                        onSubmit={e => {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            createGoal({
                                variables: {
                                    name: input.value,
                                    resolutionId: resolutionId
                                }
                            });
                            input.value = "";
                        }}
                    >
                        <input
                            ref={node => {
                                input = node;
                            }}
                        />
                        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            )}
        </Mutation>
    )
        ;
};

export default withApollo(GoalForm);
```